# Are there many bots at work?

Tags: discussion

How much of this site is currently AI? New accounts keep appearing and answering several questions, very quickly (anyway it takes me longer than 3 minutes to write an answer), without references (which is not unusual here), and they kind of seem human, in that they have a sense of self deprecating humour, but...

[Is human nature a problem for Marxists?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101457/is-human-nature-a-problem-for-marxists/101492?noredirect=1#comment302069_101492)

they also seem to lack insight and personality in some way or other (which AI does too).

Comment: I have a growing number of complaints from users that so-and-so's answer is AI-derived.  There is no way I know of to determine whether this is the case.  There is sometimes a flatness to the prose - I don't have any other way of describing it - which suggests AI may have been used. What I also suspect is that some answers are AI-derived : AI produced but decked out with, and screened by, features of the user's own style. Just one moderator's impressions.

Comment: i tend to agree @GeoffreyThomas not to be fishy, but i do wonder how much it matters. i just wish people would provide references.

Comment: i am just downvoting anything that looks like AI and flagging as spam. HTH @GeoffreyThomas

Comment: The most important question @GeoffreyThomas which you're happy or at least ok with this 'statusquo'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many (perhaps all) of the AI-generated answers are the work of a single person, Serg Z., who started spamming AI-generated answers across a large number of SE sites in mid-July, and was banned network-wide for it ([meta.SE thread](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/391584)). Since the ban, they keep creating new accounts and continuing as though nothing had happened. When those accounts are caught, the answers have for the most part been merged into Serg Z.'s account instead of deleted, so the number of bogus answers keeps growing. I think they are concentrating on the Philosophy SE now because they get more upvotes here, but it's also possible I just haven't noticed their efforts elsewhere.

If you see a recent answer on this site by a new user who starts at 1 (not 101) reputation, it's likely to be them. Note: the accounts start at 1, but don't stay there, and sometimes even go over 101 before being caught.

Comment: yeah i though serg Z would be an AI.

Comment: Some of his questions and answers were actually pretty good

Comment: Why so serious is another sock puppet of Serg Z.

Answer (score 0):

this post was written in about 2 minutes

[Is Dawkins right to reject the idea that we should respect all opinions?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101586/is-dawkins-right-to-reject-the-idea-that-we-should-respect-all-opinions)

> An average ***professional typist*** usually types around 65 to 75 WPM

it contains 371 words: they are using AI. I suppose they could have several questions open, but whatever, I could be a telepath.